# 10+1000 won't return the right number Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple script asking a user for numbers.Each number is added into a variable called counter.I want this to happen as long as counter < 100
After that i want to show the user how many numbers he entered and the result.
The problem is that if the user presses 10 and the second time 1000 he will get back number 01001000
Any ideas?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Δομημένος προγραμματισμός</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kounj.web44.net/css/apps/borderRadius.css">-->
    <style type="text/css">



button, .button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .button{
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
 }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">



function wh(){
    var i=0;
    var counter=0;
    while(counter < 100){

        i++;
        var number=prompt("Give me  num");
        counter=counter +number;


    }
    alert(i);
    alert(counter);
}


    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button" onclick="wh();">counter</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `prompt()` function returns strings, not numbers.

Comment: It's useful to read the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) before you use an unfamiliar method: *"`result` is a string containing the text entered by the user, or the value null."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are concatenating strings.  Any data input in a prompt is treated as a string.  You need to convert to integer using `parseInt()` before adding to get proper integer math.

```
function wh(){
    var i = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    while(counter < 100){
        i++;
        var input = prompt("Give me  num");
        var number = parseInt(input, 10);
        counter = counter + number;
    }
    alert(i);
    alert(counter);
}
```

Comment: noting that parseInt can also take an explicit base so that `parseInt(value, 10)` is explicit base10 interpretation, and if users type "10" with `parseInt(val,2)` that'd be decimal 2 (handy)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes explicit radix value should be used. I omitted in my haste on first submittal, but have revised.